# Is there a way to add a context menu that works only on certain tags?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to add a context menu in my Chrome extension that works only on HTML elements with a certain tag.

The list of `context`s that are specifiable [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create) doesn't suffice.

For example I need a context menu that is to be shown only on a certain custom HTML element (say `foo-bar` or it should work only on `<div>`s and not `<p>`s).

Comment: This is not possible in the current API version

Comment: @devnull69, is going to be possible in an upcoming API?

Comment: Afaik there has been no announcement yet

Comment: I filed a bug here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=393789

Comment: great ... I will follow the progress of this feature request